# Flask RestPlus/RestX: how do I share API models between Namespaces?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I've got the following structure in my Flask-RestX application:

- api_models

  - users
  - permissions
- namespaces

  - users
  - permissions

I've got a **permission_model** in *api_models/permissions* which I want to use in **user_model** in *api_models/users*. Usecase:

**Permission model:** (in *api_models/permissions.py*)

```
permission_model = permission_api.model('Permission', {
    "id": fields.String(description="Permission ID", required=True)
})
```

**User model:** (in *api_models/users.py*)

```
from .permissions import permission_model

user_model = users_api.model('User', {
    "id": fields.String(description="User ID", required=True),
    "permissions": fields.List(fields.Nested(permission_model))
})
```

I thought it's just as easy as importing models from one file to the other but the whole API breaks down when doing that ("No API definition provided."). I assume this is because they are attached to different Namespaces?

1. **Is there a workaround?**
2. **How do people use models cross Namespaces?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This actually works as expected. After spending a lot of time trying to understand why models are not shared, I've started from scratch, reviewing every line of code and when I got to the Namespace registration block....I felt incredibly stupid: I forgot to register the actual "Permissions" Namespace into the app. Did that and now works fine and models are shared as expected.

Comment: I got the same problem too. Could you explain the actual "Permissions" Namespace clearly?